# Multi-Axis Graph using the OpenPyxl library in Python

Tags: python, excel, parsing, openpyxl

I'm writing a parsing script in python and am curious as to how I could create a graph with two axis's under different data ranges.
Is this possible in openpyxl?

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

This will be possible in version 2.3.

Comment: It is a perfect answer to the question.